# NextPeer: Setting a maximum of 2 players

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nextpeer

I integrated nextpeer into my project successfully but when you search to find other players more than one person can join the game when the online version of the game is simply 2 players. How can I set an option to limit a maximum of two players per game, if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Disclosure: I work at Nextpeer.)

This can be done through the game's dashboard on the Nextpeer website. In the "Advanced Settings" tab there's a "Max amount of players" settings.

Also, don't hesitate to contact our support directly at support@nextpeer.com!